# Convergence of normal quantile approximations (or convergence of QQplot)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, weak-convergence, quantile-function

Suppose we have standard normal random variables: $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \sim N(0,1)$ and
we denote by $X_{(i)}$ the corresponding ordered statistics, i.e.

$$X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq ... \leq X_{(n)}.$$
In particular, we have $ X_{(1)} = min(X_1, ..., X_n)$
and $ X_{(n)} = max(X_1, ..., X_n)$.

Let $\Phi$ be the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal.
If I don't know $X_{(i)}$, but only its rank and distribution, intuitively the best estimate that
I can do would be its quantile, $\Phi^{-1}\left( \frac{i}{n+1} \right)$, and this is the principle in QQ-plot.

Therefore, I would like to know if the following converge in probability:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_{(i)} - \Phi^{-1}\left( \frac{i}{n+1} \right) \right)^2 $$

and what would be the rate of convergence.

Comment: Empirical investigation suggests that as $n$ increases, the distribution of that statistic seems to tend towards a normal distribution with mean just below $0.77$ and variance about $\frac2n$, so I would guess the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I checked as well and it seems that it is $O_p(1/n)$